# format and type with pandas and numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I use pandas to read csv, and I collect 2 arrays of data, which are array of tuple of str :

```
count = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', sep=",", delimiter=";", usecols = ["time", "value"])
time = np.array(count["time"])
value = np.array(count["value"])
count = [(time[i], value[i]) for i in range(len(time))]
```

However, when i launch the programm, i have this error :

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U10') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e')
```

I tried to change the format, without succeed. I think I don't understand the format ('U10'). Have you any idea ?

I am in Python 3.4

Comment: Please post an example line or two from your csv, otherwise it's very difficult for other people to debug. Also, make sure you've posted your entire code (see how to create a [mcve]).

Comment: Which line actually causes that error?

Comment: Also, `U10` means a 10-byte unicode string, which makes it arguably even harder to come up with a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the easiest way to convert Pandas.Series to Numpy array is to use `.values` attribute:

```
time = count["time"].values
value = count["value"].values
```

you may also want to convert the dtype beforehand, using one of the following functions:

- [pd.to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)
- [pd.to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)